# How to put remove cross sign in autocomplete textbox

Tags: android, listview, autocompletebox

if write text it automatically remove and if click on that cross all text remove from autocomplete text view, and how to mange click event of that cross sign [image]

Comment: What you need is a TextWatcher so you can see when a user enters characters in the TextField. And in those methods ie: afterTextChanged-> You have to write the logic to show your cross button.

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:drawableRight="@drawable/cross"` attribute of AutoCompleteTextView.

To handle click you can use the code below :

```
searchMultiAutoCompleteTextView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            final int DRAWABLE_LEFT = 0;
            final int DRAWABLE_TOP = 1;
            final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;
            final int DRAWABLE_BOTTOM = 3;

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if(event.getRawX() >= (searchMultiAutoCompleteTextView.getRight() - searchMultiAutoCompleteTextView.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {
                    // your action here

                 return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Hope it will work for you :)

Comment: I have added code to handle click on the cross button. Hope it will work. :)